# EACCES: permission denied when adding user in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, npm, dockerfile

I have a dockerized project in typescript and when I add a user in Dockerfile the docker container fails with permission denied error.

My `dockerfile` is like this:

```
FROM node:14.5.0-alpine3.12

ADD . /src

WORKDIR /src

RUN npm install -g typescript

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install && \
    adduser -u ${USER_ID} --gecos '' --disabled-password --no-create-home user

RUN chown -R user /src

USER user

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

# Run node server
CMD npm run start
```

The `start` script in my `package.json` file has the following value: `rimraf ./dist && mkdir ./dist && tsc && node dist/index.js`.

So when I build and run the container it fails to remove `dist` folder and I get the following error:

```
[Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'dist/Util'] {
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  path: 'dist/Util'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-project@1.0.0 build: `rimraf ./dist && mkdir ./dist && tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I have tried adding `RUN chmod 777 /src/dist` in my Dockerfile, but with the same result.

How can I have the user to grant write access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those build steps should be in your Dockerfile, before you switch away from the root user.  I'd suggest a setup more like the following:

```sh
FROM node:14.5.0-alpine3.12
WORKDIR /src

# Create the user up front to save a little time on rebuilds.
RUN adduser --gecos '' --disabled-password --no-create-home user

# Copy _only_ the package.json in, to save substantial time on rebuilds.
COPY package*.json ./     # includes "devDependencies": "typescript"
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application in
COPY . ./                 # .dockerignore includes node_modules

# Build it
RUN rimraf ./dist && tsc  # npm run build?

# Set the non-root user and startup metadata
USER user
CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

This will avoid needing to rebuild the application every single time you start it up, particularly since the code in the image is fixed.

Comment: So there is no way to grant access to the user and we need to build it as root. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Just a quick question. If in `index.js` want to write to a file with `fs` library, then I would have to use root in `CMD` as well and not create user at all. Isn't there a way to grant user access to write to specific folder only?

Comment: You can create a `data` subdirectory with different ownership (or possibly with a volume mounted).